# Downloadable Bash Script That Downloads Bash Scripts

Tags: bash, shell, curl

I'm working on automating provisioning of my Development VM. It does a few basic things:

1. Sets up corporate proxy stuff
2. Updates apt-get and installs a bunch of libraries
3. Installs VirtualBox Guest Additions
4. Installs RBEnv, Some Plugins and Ruby 2.2

The rest of the provisioning is going to be managed by some ruby scripts, which is why ruby is the last step of this script.

I have these things broken out into separate scripts, and I can run them very well by running

curl some.host/proxy.sh | bash

So, in the pursuit of getting to the dream on 1-command provisioning on a blank VM, I tried to make something that looks like this:

```
curl some.host/proxy.sh | bash
source ~/.bashrc
curl some.host/apt.sh | bash
curl some.host/guest_additions.sh | bash
curl some.host/development_base.sh | bash
```

Proxy Script (this completes successfully):

```
sudo sh -c "echo 'Acquire::http::proxy \"http://proxy.company.net:3000\";' > /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/01proxy"
sudo sh -c "echo 'Acquire::https::proxy \"https://proxy.company.net:3000\";' >> /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/01proxy"
echo 'export http_proxy=http://proxy.company.net:3000' >> ~/.bashrc
echo 'export HTTP_PROXY=http://proxy.company.net:3000' >> ~/.bashrc
echo 'export https_proxy=https://proxy.company.net:3000' >> ~/.bashrc
echo 'export HTTPS_PROXY=https://proxy.company.net:3000' >> ~/.bashrc
echo 'export no_proxy="company.net,localhost,127.0.0.1"' >> ~/.bashrc
echo 'export NO_PROXY="company.net,localhost,127.0.0.1"' >> ~/.bashrc
echo 'source ~/.bashrc' >> .bash_profile
```

The apt commands

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -y build-essential git-core libxml2 libxml2-dev libxslt1-dev dkms linux-headers-generic linux-headers-$(uname -r) zlib1g-dev libssl-dev tklib
```

Guest Additions (this never runs)

```
source ~/.bashrc
guest_additions_iso=VBoxGuestAdditions_4.3.28.iso
wget --directory-prefix=$HOME http://dlc-cdn.sun.com/virtualbox/4.3.28/$guest_additions_iso
sudo mount -o loop $HOME/$guest_additions_iso /mnt
sudo /mnt/VBoxLinuxAdditions.run
sudo umount -f /mnt
rm $HOME/$guest_additions_iso
```

Ruby (This never runs)

```
git clone https://github.com/sstephenson/rbenv.git ~/.rbenv
git clone https://github.com/sstephenson/ruby-build.git ~/.rbenv/plugins/ruby-build
git clone https://github.com/sstephenson/rbenv-gem-rehash.git ~/.rbenv/plugins/rbenv-gem-rehash
export PATH="$HOME/.rbenv/bin:$HOME/.rbenv/shims:$PATH"
if which rbenv > /dev/null; then eval "$(rbenv init -)"; fi
rbenv install 2.1.5
rbenv global 2.1.5
gem install bundler
```

This works great, up until the guest_additions script.

The apt-get install takes a few minutes, and when it's done, the script just stops. It never attempts to go out and fetch / run the next script.

What would be the proper way to do this?

EDIT:

Okay, lots of comments, which I'll try to address here instead of in comments.

1. What are your scripts actually doing?

Fair enough point, which I've added above. I thought perhaps the mere idea of the script that downloads and executes other scripts was off base or would have some caveats in and of itself, so I did not include the scripts at first to avoid busying the question with too many details

2. What happens when it stalls?

It doesn't stall, persay, it just acts like the guest additions and developer base lines aren't there.

3. Why not Chef or something else

I may look into using puppet or something at some point, but at this point I don't want to.

Comment: What happens when that script runs exactly? What does that script do? Where/when is this set of commands being run?

Comment: That, well, depends on *why* it stops, and reproducing that depends on details not shown here. Are you using `set -e` or an ERR trap? Is this script itself having its stdin eaten by a child process? (If that's the `apt-get install`, for instance, running it `</dev/null` will prevent it from consuming stdin).

Comment: ...anyhow, you'll need to build a reproducer for us to be of much assistance here. This kind of problem depends on the details; pseudocode that doesn't actually reproduce the issue isn't much help.

Comment: Sounds like you want to use something like Chef. Or is this part of a Chef recipe?

Comment: agree with all of above. You could also add `set -vx` in your `guest_additions.sh` and see what command is executing when it stalls. Good luck.

Comment: Made a bunch of edits to address comments. Thanks!

Comment: 1. Are you sure that `apt-get install ....` has really finished? That's a lot of pkgs to install. 2. Do you have a #!/bin/{sh,bash,ksh} at the top of the apt-get script? (It is a separate script, right?). If yes, try removing that line, and then "source" that script, like `. apt-get_installer.sh` instead. 3. (Without being able to look over the exact code, I can only make these half-baked guesses ;-) ! ) 4. Also, I didn't see that you had posted a reply. Include userIDs like @shellter in your message to see that "we" see them. Good luck